# Put an img just at the right of a table for some rows # version 2

Tags: html, image, html-table

I want a table with a image at the right of the table.

Here is what I want (did on paint) :

[image]

Here is my html : (don't care about "if" in the "jsp"). 
For example the last line of code (after the "if") : `<td class="noborder"><img src="img/refresh.png" class="refreshButton" alt="Refresh" id="sameRightsAsRefresh" href="Javascript:void;"></img></td>`

and here is the css :

```
table td,table th 
{
    border: 1px ridge black;
    padding: 3px;
}

td.noborder {
    border:0
}
```

I want to have my button refresh at the right of the SameRightsAs, username and lastname.

The full code :

```
<!-- FIRST TABLE : REQUESTOR -->
            <form id="form" method="post" action="mainServlet?command=FillBlanks&amp;">
                <p class="tableHead">Request For:</p>
                <table class="requestor">

                    <tr>
                        <td class="reqCellLabel">Username:</td>
                        <td class="reqCellAnswer" id="oracleUsername"><input id="oracleUsernameText" class="reqCellAnswer" onchange="fillBlanks(this.id,this.value)"
                            type="text" name="Requestor" <%if( Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("isCreation")) == 1){%> readonly <%}%>></input></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="reqCellLabel">Oracle Employee #:</td>
                        <td class="reqCellAnswer" id="oracleEmployeeNumber"><input id="oracleEmployeeNumberText" class="reqCellAnswer"
                            type="text" name="Requestor" ></input></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="reqCellLabel">Last name:</td>
                        <td class="reqCellAnswer" id="lastName"><input id="lastNameText" class="reqCellAnswer"
                            type="text" name="Requestor" ></input></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td class="reqCellLabel">First name:</td>
                        <td class="reqCellAnswer" id="firstName"><input id="firstNameText" class="reqCellAnswer"
                            type="text" name="Requestor" ></input></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td class="reqCellLabel">Timezone:</td>
                        <td class="reqCellAnswer" id="timeZone"><input id="timeZoneText" class="reqCellAnswer"
                            type="text" name="Requestor" ></input></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td class="reqCellLabel">Default Printer:</td>
                        <td class="reqCellAnswer" id="defaultPrinter"><input id="defaultPrinterText" class="reqCellAnswer"
                            type="text" name="Requestor"  value=""></input></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="reqCellLabel">Employee is a buyer ?</td>
                        <td class="reqCellAnswer" id="employeeIsBuyer"><input id="employeeIsBuyerText" class="reqCellAnswer"
                            type="text" name="Requestor" ></input></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="reqCellLabel">Same rights as :</td>
                        <td class="reqCellAnswer" id="sameRightsAs"><input id="sameRightsAsText" name="sameRightsAsText" class="reqCellAnswer" onchange="sameRightsAs(this.id,this.value)"
                            type="text" name="Requestor" <%if( Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("isCreation")) == 0){%> disabled <%}%>></input></td>
                        <%if( Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("isCreation")) == 1){%> <td class="noborder"><img src="img/refresh.png" class="refreshButton" alt="Refresh" id="sameRightsAsRefresh" href="Javascript:void;"></img></td><%}%>
                    </tr>
                </table>

            </form>
</body
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this?
pay attention that all of your text fields have the same name, and when you submit the form the last one will be the accepted value, but maybe is an example, I hope :)

```
<table class="requestor">

                    <tr>
                        <td class="reqCellLabel">Username:</td>
                        <td class="reqCellAnswer" id="oracleUsername"><input id="oracleUsernameText" class="reqCellAnswer" onchange="fillBlanks(this.id,this.value)"
                            type="text" name="Requestor"></input></td>
                        <td class="noborder" id="oracleUsername"><img src="refresh.jpg" width="16" height="16" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="reqCellLabel">Oracle Employee #:</td>
                        <td class="reqCellAnswer" id="oracleEmployeeNumber"><input id="oracleEmployeeNumberText" class="reqCellAnswer"
                            type="text" name="Requestor" ></input></td>
                        <td class="noborder" id="oracleEmployeeNumber">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="reqCellLabel">Last name:</td>
                        <td class="reqCellAnswer" id="lastName"><input id="lastNameText" class="reqCellAnswer"
                            type="text" name="Requestor" ></input></td>
                        <td class="noborder" id="lastName">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td class="reqCellLabel">First name:</td>
                        <td class="reqCellAnswer" id="firstName"><input id="firstNameText" class="reqCellAnswer"
                            type="text" name="Requestor" ></input></td>
                        <td class="noborder" id="firstName">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td class="reqCellLabel">Timezone:</td>
                        <td class="reqCellAnswer" id="timeZone"><input id="timeZoneText" class="reqCellAnswer"
                            type="text" name="Requestor" ></input></td>
                        <td class="noborder" id="timeZone">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td class="reqCellLabel">Default Printer:</td>
                        <td class="reqCellAnswer" id="defaultPrinter"><input id="defaultPrinterText" class="reqCellAnswer"
                            type="text" name="Requestor"  value=""></input></td>
                        <td class="noborder" id="defaultPrinter">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="reqCellLabel">Employee is a buyer ?</td>
                        <td class="reqCellAnswer" id="employeeIsBuyer"><input id="employeeIsBuyerText" class="reqCellAnswer"
                            type="text" name="Requestor" ></input></td>
                        <td class="noborder" id="employeeIsBuyer">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="reqCellLabel">Same rights as :</td>
                        <td class="reqCellAnswer" id="sameRightsAs"><input id="employeeIsBuyerText" class="reqCellAnswer"
                            type="text" name="Requestor" ></input></td>
                        <td class="noborder" id="sameRightsAs"><img src="refresh.jpg" alt="" width="16" height="16" /></td>

                    </tr>
                </table>
```

Comment: Ok I will understand your code and answer you if it's work (or not).
It's not an  example but I don't use the name, only the Id with "document.getElementById(...)"

Thanks a lot for your answer by the way

Comment: when you submit a form the name parameter is the one that you will find in the collection in the next step